# google map V3 - private kml feed

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to switch from virtual (VE) earth to google map (GM).

It is pretty easy to overlay a georss feed over a map in VE as well as in GM:

```
var georssLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('www.bla.com/kmls/k1');
georssLayer.setMap(map);
```

Unfortunately, google requires the 'kml address' to be public. What can I do to achieve the same functionality if my address is not public (e.g. when the user has to login before [s]he can enjoy the map)?

Thanks.

Christian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've thought about this issue before and this is the solution I've come up with (although I haven't implemented it yet).

- The server code that generates the html page in which the map is embedded should generate a temporary token that is tied to the current user in the database.
- Make the KML address public, but pass the temporary token to it as a query parameter
- Include logic in the KML server code that checks the passed token to be sure it is valid
- The token should only be valid for a limited time.

This solution will be slightly less secure than full id/pw authentication on the KML resource. But by using a short lived token, it may be good enough, depending on your requirements.

Comment: Interesting solution. Should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Now that it's 2023 and using cloud providers is pretty common, I thought I'd give a more specific answer.

All object storage solutions for the top 3 cloud providers have some sort of public, but time-limited access controls. I would probably use that for sharing my KMLs with Google Maps.

1. Amazon S3 has [presigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)
2. Microsoft Azure Storage has [shared access signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delegate-access-with-shared-access-signature)
3. Google Cloud storage has [signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls)

All different ways of saying "temporary token." The nice thing is that you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

#### Cavaet

Google asks developers to avoid using temporary tokens because "these can unintentionally prevent caching." See the bullet points here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#performance